# Using ShareLatex my Bibliography crashed

Tags: errors, citing, sharelatex

I learned Latex using ShareLatex. So far, everything went just fine up until some point when suddenly my latex document gave me error messages that my citations cant be found.

I really need help with this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: And also: You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I can give you access to the whole file if you think that helps

Comment: @user56240: No, not the whole file. Make a copy for yourself, reduce this copy to a minimum, but it should still reproduce the error. This will probably help other users here to find out what might be the origin of the error(s)

Comment: My latex document starts like this: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
this is the standard setting
my citations are \cite{williams_incentives_1998}

the odd thing is, that the error ocurred suddenly without any dramatic change.

Comment: this is an example of my bibtex file:
this is an example of my bibtex file:
@article{ashley_executive_2004,
 Author = {Ashley, Allan S. and Yang, Simon {SM}},
 Date = {2004},
 Date-Modified = {2014-07-01 21:20:30 +0000},
 File = {Ashley, A. S., & Yang, S. S. M. (2004). Executive compensation and earnings persistence. Journal of Business Ethics, 50(4), 369-382..pdf:

Comment: I use zotero for capturing all the citations from pdf, the internet or databases and export them as bibtex file. so far this has worked without any problems. Although my latex citation commands are exactly like the commands in my bibtex file, my system creates almost for all citations an error message

Comment: @user56240: I neither use `ShareLaTeX` nor `zotero` at all, I am not the man able to help you in this, but certainly other can and will do, I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing? As it stands, there is nothing obviously wrong with your code or with using it on ShareLaTeX.

Comment: I solved it yesterday. It was too simple for me to notice. One of the last sources I inserted before it crashed incorporated a "%" which in latex means that nothing that follows this command will be recognized. And that is was LateX did. All the sources afterwards would not be taken into account. The 5 sources before were accurately shown.

Comment: Needless to say that the problem was within the Bibtex file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it caused by an unescaped % in the bib-file.